# Select values in pandas groupby series, less than, and subsequently, greate than, a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as follow

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subjects':['A','A','B','C','A','A','B','B','C','C'],
                  'value':[3,5,5,6,7,2,4,8,9,2]})

subjects    value
A            3
A            5
B            5
C            6
A            7
A            2
B            4
B            8
C            9
C            2
```

Now I want to select those `subjects`, where at some point `value` is less than 5 and becomes greater than 5 at some other subsequent point coming after the point where `value` is less than 5.
In this data frame it will be A and B.

I have tried this:

```
df[df.groupby('subjects').value.apply(lambda x: x > 5)]
```

But it selects those having `value` greater than 5, and I want initial `value`s to less than 5 and if there is a change in value and subsequent `value` is greater than 5, then return those `subjects`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) for `True`s for rows after match less like `5` and then filter rows in `df1` if greater like `5`:

```
thresh = 5
m1 = df['value'] < thresh

df1 = df[m1.groupby(df['subjects']).cummax()] 
print (df1)
  subjects  value
0        A      3
1        A      5
4        A      7
5        A      2
6        B      4
7        B      8
9        C      2

out = df1.loc[df1['value'] > thresh, 'subjects'].unique().tolist()
print (out)
['A', 'B']
```

Performance:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000

df = pd.DataFrame({'subjects': np.random.randint(500, size=N),
                   'value':np.random.randint(7, size=N)})
print (df)


thresh = 5
m1 = df['value'] < thresh
df1 = df[m1.groupby(df['subjects']).cummax()] 
out = df1.loc[df1['value'] > thresh, 'subjects'].unique().tolist()
print (len(out))

def lt_then_gt_threshold(v, thresh=5):
    m = (v<thresh).cummax()
    return (v[m]>thresh).any()

subjs = df.groupby('subjects')['value'].apply(lt_then_gt_threshold)

print (len(subjs[subjs].index))
```

---

```
In [60]: %%timeit
    ...: 
    ...: thresh = 5
    ...: m1 = df['value'] < thresh
    ...: df1 = df[m1.groupby(df['subjects']).cummax()] 
    ...: out = df1.loc[df1['value'] > thresh, 'subjects'].unique().tolist()
    ...: 
2.44 ms ± 9.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [61]: %%timeit
    ...: df.groupby('subjects')['value'].apply(lt_then_gt_threshold)
    ...: 
266 ms ± 613 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Neat. I think it's "strictly greater than 5", hence `> 5` not `>=`

Comment: @smci - Ya, but then is not matched `A`, so I guess need `>=`, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I think you have to do the groupby() first, then apply the m1, m2 masking within a group. Otherwise seems too risky to debug, esp. as `subjects` column is all over the place.

Comment: Ah, actually, your mask m2 is slightly wrong because it only looks at the *immediately* subsequent value to see if it's > 5, but that fails on subject 'A', because its values stay 5,5 then increase to 7

Comment: @smci - I think first solution was wrong, so changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using logical masking. Then we use `.cummax()` as a shortcut to logical-and that forward. Now we have a mask which identifies every element subsequent to the first value that was < 5. It's then simple to compare `(v[m]>5).any()`:

```
def lt_then_gt_threshold(v, thresh=5):
    m = (v<thresh).cummax()
    return (v[m]>thresh).any()

>>> subjs = df.groupby('subjects')['value'].apply(lt_then_gt_5)

subjects
A     True
B     True
C    False

>>> subjs[subjs==True].index.tolist()

['A', 'B']
```

Comment: ya, only performance... if many groups really bad

Comment: @jezrael: I think performance is as good as yours. Remember, Python/pandas does early termination on the `(v[m]>5).any()`, so it will return quite quickly.

Comment: hmmm, I suggest it from `groupby.apply` is slow if is used some custom function, but sure, depends of data.

Comment: @jezrael: Note in this case that after the `.groupby()`, we can just slice `['value']` and pass only that series of integers into the apply function.

Comment: because filtering per groups here vs not per groups in my solution - so there is difference in performance

Comment: ya, depends of data. if some 1000 groups, 10k rows I think there is perfomance difference.

Comment: if 10 groups, 100 rows it is OK.

Comment: Added performance comparison to my answer.